Stepping down as moderator
I'm stepping down as moderator of Bitcoin StackExchange.
I find that I haven't been able to make the needed time commitment to the site.
Thanks to Murch, Stephen, and the StackExchange CM's. It's been a good run.

Thank you for your work and best wishes to you in your life

Sorry to see you go Nick, I've only been here for a little while but I've seen you round a lot and you've done a lot of good work for the site. Best of luck for whatever you're moving on to

Thank you, Nick, for all of the time you have put into helping Bitcoin.SE, and best of luck in your future endeavors.

Well, I am sorry to hear that. :-/
Thank you for all the work that you have put in.

I'm sad to see you go! Thanks for all your work.
